# Background css in php

Tags: php, css, background

I used style.php as a style file..
and this is a part of that file

```
.<?php echo $cty2; ?> {
background: url(images/<?php echo $cty2; ?>.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

when I go to style.php (browser), this will appear

```
.newyorkny {
background: url(images/newyorkny.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

But the page background didn't appear!

---

and when I changed this

```
.<?php echo $cty2; ?> {
background: url(images/<?php echo $cty2; ?>.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

to this (without php)

```
.newyorkny {
background: url(images/newyorkny.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

then the BG appeared

so, how I force the BG to appear with php style?

======== Edited ============

And this is the style.php file

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/css ");

?>

@font-face {
font-family: "Segoe WPC";
src: url("http://cdn-resources.windowsphone.com/Resources/Fonts/SegoeWPCRegular/Latin1_1252/87c56796-f4c3-4861-9f31-035d303c63ce-1.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Segoe WPC Light";
src: url("http://cdn-resources.windowsphone.com/Resources/Fonts/SegoeWPCLight/Latin1_1252/bd84c8dc-054a-427a-9fde-3ebb63965f38-1.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: "Segoe WPC Black";
src: url("http://cdn-resources.windowsphone.com/Resources/Fonts/SegoeWPCBlack/Latin1_1252/f513a30a-82ae-4466-acac-96337207a433-1.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal;
font-weight: bold;
}

body {
color:#a8a8a8;
font-family: 'Segoe WPC', Segoe UI, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
background: #141414;
}

img { margin: 2px; }

h1 {
margin-top: 5px;
font-weight:400;
}

a {
color:#a8a8a8;/*333*/
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
color:#eee;
}

option {
font-weight: bold;
}
option:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

img { border: 0 }

input, select, textarea {
font-family: 'Segoe WPC', Segoe UI, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
border:1px solid #D9D9D9;
border-top:1px solid #C0C0C0;
font-size:14px;
outline:none;
padding:5px;
}
input:hover, select:hover, textarea:hover{
border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
border-top: 1px solid #777;
}
input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus {
border:1px solid #2a2a2a;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
input#search {
width: 176px;
background: #f0f0f0;
border:2px solid #000;
font-size:14px;
outline:none;
padding:5px;
color:#aaa;
margin-top: 10px;
}
input#search:hover {
background: #fff;
color: #202020;
}
input#search:focus {
background: #fff;
color: #202020;
}
hr { 
border:none;
color:white;
height:1px;
background:#ccc;
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 600, from(#ccc), to(#fff)); 
}

/* Selectie */
::selection {
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
::-moz-selection {
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
::-webkit-selection {
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}

/*General*/

#header {
font-family: 'Open Sans', Segoe UI, sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 7px 10px 13px 10px;
height: 69px;
}

#content {
width:1006px;
margin:20px auto 0 auto;
}

.content {
border: 3px solid #000;
width: 1000px;
height: 575px;
background: #fafafa;
}
.Freeze {
background: url(images/bg_freeze.png) no-repeat;
}
.Cold {
background: url(images/bg_cold.png) no-repeat;
}


/* new york */
<?php
function PageMain() {
    global $TMPL;
    $resultSettings = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(getSettings($querySettings)));
            $year = date("Y");
            $month = date("m"); 
    # Detecteaza locatia IP-ului vizitatorului
    include("includes/geoipcity.inc");
    include("includes/geoipregionvars.php");

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $gi = geoip_open("includes/GeoLiteCity.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
    $record = geoip_record_by_addr($gi, $ip);
    geoip_close($gi);

    $city = $record->city;

    # Hotaraste ce oras este folosit
    if(isset($_GET['city'])) { # Daca e setat ?city schimba
        $city = htmlspecialchars($_GET['city']);
    } elseif (empty($city)) { # Daca nu deteacteaza locatia IP-ului, pune default
        $city = $resultSettings[1];
    }

    # Preia informatia (cURL pentru formatul UTF-8)
    $city = urlencode($city);
    $city = utf8_encode($city);
    $url = 'http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather='.$city.'&hl=en';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    $utf8 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($utf8);
    # Seteaza preferinta formatului temperaturii
    if($_GET['f'] == 'f') {
        setcookie("format", 'fahrenhite', time() + 10080);  
        $TMPL['cf'] = 'f';
        $TMPL['f'] = 'c';
    } elseif($_GET['f'] == 'c') {
        setcookie("format", 'celsius', time() + 10080); 
        $TMPL['cf'] = 'c';
        $TMPL['f'] = 'f';
    } elseif($_COOKIE['format'] == '') {
        $TMPL['cf'] = 'c';
        $TMPL['f'] = 'f';
    } elseif($_COOKIE['format'] == 'fahrenhite') {
        $TMPL['cf'] = 'f';
        $TMPL['f'] = 'c';
    } elseif($_COOKIE['format'] == 'celsius') {
        $TMPL['cf'] = 'c';
        $TMPL['f'] = 'f';
    }

    # Defineste radacinile in variabile cu xpath
    $information = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_information");
    $current = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/current_conditions");
    $forecast = $xml->xpath("/xml_api_reply/weather/forecast_conditions");
$cty = $information[0]->city['data'];
$ctyy = utf8_encode($cty);

    if(isset($_COOKIE['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['password'])) {

        $query = sprintf('SELECT * from users where username = "%s" and password ="%s"', 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']), 
        mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['password']));


        if(mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($query))) {
            $user = $_COOKIE['username'];       
            if($_GET['fav'] == '1') {

                $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO favorites (`username`, `location`) values ('%s', '%s')",
                mysql_real_escape_string($user),
                mysql_real_escape_string($city));
                mysql_query($query);

            }

            if(isset($_GET['city'])) {

                $TMPL['fav'] = '?city='.$_GET['city'].'&fav=1';

            } else {

                $TMPL['fav'] = '?fav=1';
            }


        } else {
            $user = 'anonymous';
            $TMPL['notLogged'] = '<despartitor></despartitor>You must be logged in to add favorites';
        }
    } else { 
        $user = 'anonymous';
        $TMPL['notLogged'] = '<despartitor></despartitor>You must be logged in to add a city to favorites.';
    }

    $cookieFormat = $TMPL['cf']; # Seteaza variabila cookies format, ca s-o pot folosi si in rows

    $TMPL_old = $TMPL; $TMPL = array();
    $skin = new skin('welcome/rows'); $all = '';

    # Citeste formatul ales de user, si arata-i informatiile in formatul ales de el
    if($cookieFormat == 'f') {
        foreach($forecast as $foreca) {
            $TMPL['day'] = $foreca->day_of_week['data'];
            $TMPL['low'] = $foreca->low['data'].'&deg;';
            $TMPL['high'] = $foreca->high['data'].'&deg;';
            $TMPL['icon'] = str_replace(array('/ig', '.gif'), array('', '.png'), $foreca->icon['data']);
            $TMPL['condition'] = $foreca->condition['data'];
            $all .= $skin->make();
        }
    } else {
        foreach($forecast as $foreca) {
            $TMPL['day'] = $foreca->day_of_week['data'];
            $TMPL['low'] = round(($foreca->low['data'] - 32) /1.8, 0).'&deg;'; # Converteste din Fahrenhite in Celsius
            $TMPL['high'] = round(($foreca->high['data'] - 32) /1.8, 0).'&deg;'; # Converteste din Fahrenhite in Celsius
            $TMPL['icon'] = str_replace(array('/ig', '.gif'), array('', '.png'), $foreca->icon['data']);
            $TMPL['condition'] = $foreca->condition['data'];
            $all .= $skin->make();
        }
    }

    $TMPL = $TMPL_old; unset($TMPL_old);
    $TMPL['rows'] = $all;

    if($cookieFormat == 'f') {

            $TMPL['city'] = $information[0]->city['data'];
            $TMPL['temp'] = $current[0]->temp_f['data'].'&deg;';

            $cty = trim($TMPL['city']);
            $cty2 = str_replace(" ", "", "$cty");
            $cty2 = str_replace(",", "", "$cty2");
            $cty2 = strtolower($cty2);
            $ct = $TMPL['city'];
            $TMPL['weather'] = $cty2;
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO city (city, css, year, month) VALUES ('$city','$cty2','$year','$month')");
            $year = date("Y");
            $month = date("m");

        } else {

            $TMPL['city'] = $information[0]->city['data'];
            $TMPL['temp'] = $current[0]->temp_c['data'].'&deg;';

            $cty = trim($TMPL['city']);
            $cty2 = str_replace(" ", "", "$cty");
            $cty2 = str_replace(",", "", "$cty2");
            $cty2 = strtolower($cty2);
            $ct = $TMPL['city'];
            $TMPL['weather'] = $cty2;

        $ce = $TMPL['city'];



$query2 = "SELECT * FROM city WHERE city='$ce' ";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {

        $visits = $row2['visits'];

        }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result2)){



        mysql_query("UPDATE city SET visits='$visits'+1 WHERE city='$ce' ");



    }
    else
    {
        $visits = '1';

        $query3 = "INSERT INTO city (city, css, visits) VALUES ('$ce','$cty2','$visits')";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    $cty2 = utf8_encode($cty2);



$con = mysql_connect("localhost","hatim_wea","*F7W,vrBEzC=");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$sel = mysql_select_db("hatim_weather", $con) or die();
$ce = $TMPL['city'];
$queryw = "SELECT * FROM city where city='$ce' ";
$resultw = mysql_query($queryw,$con) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$numw = "mysql_num_rows($queryw)";

    while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($resultw)) {
        $sete = $roww["city"];
        $visits = $roww["visits"];

        $cess = $roww["css"];


    }   
    if (mysql_num_rows($resultw)){

$ss = utf8_encode($cess);

echo"

.$ss {
background: url(images/$ss.jpg);
} 

";
}


        }





}

require_once('./includes/config.php');
require_once('./includes/skins.php');
require_once('./includes/functions.php');

mysql_connect($conf['host'], $conf['user'], $conf['pass']);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_select_db($conf['name']);

$TMPL['content'] = PageMain();

?>
```

Comment: I think there is no wrong or right answer to your question because you don't really ask for something. There are literally a hundred ways to solve it, but you might just want to learn about something very basic like what a CSS selector is. Can you share a bit more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing this completely wrong, why not just make it a .css file and then include it according to city, and what do you mean that it showed the background? Where?

Include it according to the city, I mean like:

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.$cty2.'" />';
```

Comment: background i mean this " background: url(images/newyorkny.jpg) no-repeat; "
it appear in the style.php (on fireFox) but the index.php ther is no background

Comment: So are you using <style> etc?

Comment: no,

I think the prblem in the encoding of $cty2,
what is the perfect encode for this?

Comment: it came from:

            $cty = trim($TMPL['city']);
            $cty2 = str_replace(" ", "", "$cty");
            $cty2 = str_replace(",", "", "$cty2");
            $cty2 = strtolower($cty2);
            $ct = $TMPL['city'];
            $TMPL['weather'] = $cty2;

and its result if the city is New York NY is:
newyorkny

Comment: See where you have `"$cty"` and `"$cty2"`? I suggest taking those double-quotes out and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content type, the server is serving your style.php as text/html and the browser expects text/css, to set the content type use the `header` function.

```
header('Content-Type: text/css');
```